# How to set initial state of rnn as parameter in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

When one uses `dynamic_rnn`, a parameter called `initial_state` is required. An easy solution is

```
initial_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
```

But I want to set the initial state as a parameter which can be optimized, how should I do?

I can define two trainable_variables called `h0` and `c0`, which are two vectors. But `dynamic_rnn` requires two matrixes where the first dimension is `batch_size`. How could I expand the vector `h0` to a matrix whose each row is `h0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you did something like this?

```
initial_state_vector = tf.get_variable('initial_state_vector', [1, state_size])
initial_state = tf.tile(initial_state_vector, batch_size)
```

Then you can supply the `initial_state` variable to the LSTM and it will be the proper size.

Comment: It's not clear to me from the documentation that `tf.tile` keeps all the values linked together (to make sure you only learn `state_size` many values instead of `batch_size * state_size` many values). Do you know if that is the case?

Comment: Yes. When you tile a vector then it will tie all of those weights together. I didn't test the code in my answer so I might have got something slightly off but this basic strategy should work.

Comment: Actually, it should be <code>initial_state = tf.tile(initial_state_vector, [batch_size, 1])</code> The second parameter of tf.tile should be a list or a tensor where each item tiles each dimension of initial_state_vector.

Comment: When I try either of the answers, I get an error `'Tensor' object is not iterable`, any idea why ?